# DataFrame.withColumn() works very slow using a costomized UDF for a pipline

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, user-defined-functions

Nowadays, I am implementing a fuzzy classifier using ML and Pipeline pypark APIs, my problem is in the last stage when the Rule Bases(RB) has been generated and I want to predict the result as a new 'prediction' column.

For this purpose, I use df.withColumn() that uses the infrence_udf to make a decision as the fuzzy principles. In this way, I don't know why it doesn't work with big datasets.
(if I move the four last methods inside classes, I faces with serialization problem.)
Everything is ok with very small datasets, an with big datasets the rules are generated and transmitted correctly, the problem is just in the slowness of withColumn?! Do you have any similar experience or ideas?

```
class FuzzyClassifier(Estimator, HasFeaturesCol, HasLabelCol,HasInputCol, HasPredictionCol):
    .
    .
    .
    def _fit(self, df):
        rb_p,rb_n=self.GenerateRules(df)             
        fuzzyModel=FuzzyModel(labelCol=self.getLabelCol(),featuresCol=self.getFeaturesCol(),RB_Pos=rb_p,RB_Neg=rb_n)               
        return (fuzzyModel)

class FuzzyModel(Model,HasFeaturesCol, HasLabelCol):
    .
    .
    .
    def _transform(self, df):         
            RB_N=self.getRB_Neg()
            RB_P=self.getRB_Pos()
            MFsParams=Fuzzifier().getMFsParams()   
            df = df.withColumn('prediction', infrence_udf(RB_P,RB_N,MFsParams)('features'))
            return   df 

def infrence_udf(RB_P,RB_N,MFsParams):
            return F.udf(lambda l: infrence(l,RB_P,RB_N,MFsParams), DoubleType()) 

def infrence(sampleRow,RB_P,RB_N,MFsParams):
        p=getCoverageDegree(sampleRow,RB_P,MFsParams)
        n=getCoverageDegree(sampleRow,RB_N,MFsParams)
        if  p > n :       #  degree 'PositiveClass'  > 'NegetiveClass'
            predictedLabed = 1.0
        elif p < n:    #  degree  'PositiveClass'  > 'NegetiveClass'
            predictedLabed = 0.0
        else:
             predictedLabed = random.randrange(0, 2)
        return float(predictedLabed)

def getCoverageDegree(sampleRow, RB,MFsParams):        
    # calc sum of the mathching degrees of all rules and each sample row   
    RB=np.array(RB.reshape(RB.shape[0],RB.shape[2]))
    x=np.array([sampleRow,]*len(RB))  # sampleRow is replicated
    degree=np.sum(np.array([getMatchingDegree(xp,r,MFsParams) for xp,r in zip(x,RB)]))
    return degree


def getMatchingDegree(xp, r_i,MFsParams):  
    mfValues=np.array([trimf(xp_i,MFsParams[a_ji-1]) for xp_i,a_ji in zip(xp,r_i)])        
    m=np.prod(mfValues, axis=0)
    return m

def trimf(z,p):
        a,b,c=p[0],p[1],p[2]
        if (z<=a) or (z>=c):
            y = 0
        elif (a <= z <= b):
            y = (z-a) / (b-a)
        elif (b <= z <= c):
            y = (c-z) / (c-b)
        return y
```

Comment: The problem you're experiencing is likely due to the way a UDF works: for every row, Spark must transform a Java object to a Python object, then do the manipulations you want and then bring it back to a Java object. If you can, use ML algorithms that come with the framework (Spark has MLlib), or try using `pandas_udf`s to work on larger chunks, rather than row by row.

Comment: @Oliver W. Thank you for your quick comment, The problem is that pandas-udf doesn't work with array (I think!) am I right? the features column is a vector of int that should be the base of prediction.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way how you have coded it.
I would recommend 
1. rewrite the functions using spark
2. keep getCoverageDegree before withcolumn statement

Comment: @ user3600673, thanks for your answer, can you explain more "rewrite the functions using spark", I need to inference based on my classifier that can not be done by the built-in functions of spark, so I use user-defined functions (UDF).??

Comment: @fatemeAghaei, the code is making me feel inception! Too many function inside function calls.
rewrite I meant to use the spark core abstraction instead of pandas(rdd/dataset instead of np).. this will be fruitful for the spark engine to optimize.